# InfluxDB - Aggregate data on state duration

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I have a measurement in InfluxDB that keeps track of the status of a system. For example, consider the following measures:

```
03/22/18 00:00:00AM    STATUS_A
03/22/18 09:00:00AM    STATUS_B
03/22/18 13:00:00AM    STATUS_C
03/22/18 18:00:00AM    STATUS_B
03/22/18 19:00:00AM    STATUS_D
03/22/18 21:00:00AM    STATUS_A
```

What I need to do now is to derive how long the system was in each state every day. In the above example, the desired result is something like

```
STATUS_A    12h (from 00:00 to 09:00 and from 21:00 to 24:00)
STATUS_B    5h (from 09:00 to 13:00 and from 18:00 to 19:00)
STATUS_C    5h (from 13:00 to 18:00)
STATUS_D    2h (from 09:00 to 21:00)
```

I'm very new to the TICK stack, so I could be missing something quite elementary. I was thinking to use Kapacitor to create the aggregate result, but I don't really know how to obtain the result

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned TICK stack so I assume you are using InfluxDB version 1.

It is feasible to report the total duration for a given state in InfluxDB but only in Flux not InfluxQL (easily).
You could try these steps:

1. Enable Flux in v1.8 with the configuration change [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/installation/)
2. Sample Flux could be:

   from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen") |> range(start: 2018-03-20T00:00:00Z, stop: 2018-03-20T23:59:59Z) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName")  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r._value == "STATUS_A", column: "state", unit: 1h)

Again it's still not possible to do it yet in InfluxQL though the community has been waiting for this for a while. See more details [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7581).